# How do I pass multiple commands to START in Windows Command Line?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

How do I pass multiple commands to `start`?

I tried

```
start "window title" echo 1 && echo 2
```

But, predictably, start only gets "echo 1" and thus "1" is echoed in the new window, and "2" is echoed in the first window.

Is there some way to "escape" the `&&` operator, or another way to pass multiple commands into `start` so they run successively in the new window?

Comment: Do you want both 1 and 2 to be echo-ed on the same window?

Comment: Yes, in the newly spawned window from `start`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How do I pass multiple commands to start?

You need to use the `cmd /k` option and also quote the `command` you are running.

The following command will work:

```
start "window title" cmd /k "echo 1 && echo 2"
```

where:

```
Options   
   /C     Run Command and then terminate

   /K     Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt.
          This is useful for testing, to examine variables

   Command : The command, program or batch script to be run.
             This can even be several commands separated with '&' 
             (the whole should also be surrounded by "quotes")
```

Source: [CMD.exe (Command Shell) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [CMD.exe (Command Shell) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) - Start a new CMD shell and (optionally) run a command/executable program.

Comment: Thanks, and what if one of my command parameters has quotation marks in it?

Comment: [Quotes, Escape Characters, Delimiters - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

Comment: In this particular case you don't need to do anything as `start "window title" cmd /k "echo "1" && echo "2""` works

Comment: I've found that nested quotation marks don't always work.  So escaping per @ReddyLutonadio might be a good approach.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski And as I've commented on his answer "That puts a space before the `1`"

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to escape the `&` with `^`.

```
start "window title" echo 1 ^&^& echo 2
```

Comment: Hmm. That puts a space before the `1`

Comment: Combining both approaches works without a space: `start "window title" cmd /k echo 1 ^&^& echo 2`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this might help someone with a similar issue (wanting to launch a cmd window with a title, echoing a string of commands, then executing those commands - useful for cmd prompt debug):

```
start "net stop w32time && net start w32time" cmd /k echo net stop w32time ^^^&^^^& net start w32time ^&^& net stop w32time ^&^& net start w32time
```